# AttributeError: 'YY' object has no attribute 'xx"

Tags: python, class, oop

let's say i have a class named YY that is the child of a parent class (ZZ) thus , YY should be heritating all functions and attributes of ZZ . But it is not the case for my code !

```
class ZZ:
    def __init__(self,xx):
        self.xx=xx


class YY(ZZ,AA):
    def __init__(self, référence,position):
        self.référence=référence
        self.position=position
    def nearest_position(self,matrix,a):
        for w in range (len(matrix)):
            if (matrix[w][2]==self.xx):
                #some codeee

def main():        

   yy=YY('ab',23)
   yy.nearest_position(matrix,('ab',300))
```

it says that 'YY' object has no attribute 'xx' but xx should be heritated from ZZ. I'm really confused!

Comment: you should call `super()` in init for YY and also add xx as a parameter in yy=YY('ab',23)

Answer (score 1):

You must call super() on the parent class, and pass the appropriate parameter.

For instance, something like this:

```
class AA:
    pass


class ZZ:
    def __init__(self, xx):
        self.xx = xx


class YY(ZZ, AA):
    def __init__(self, référence, position):
        super().__init__(42)
        self.référence = référence
        self.position = position

    def nearest_position(self, a):
        return f'YOP: {a}'


yy = YY('ab', 23)
print(yy.nearest_position('ab'), yy.xx)
```

**output:**

```
YOP: ab 42
```

Comment: actually the ZZ class has many others attributes but the only attribute i need to heritate from it is the xx. So do i have to put all the attributes in the super().__init__ or only the xx? Thank you for your time

Comment: You probably need to pass them all.